# Validation rule that limits what products to add to opportunity by oppRecordId not showing error

Tags: validation-rule

I have a validation rule on the Opportunity Product object...it's the only one that i could reference the Opportunity object and the Product 2 object.

```
AND(Opportunity.RecordType.Name = "Happy Fun Times", 
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(Product2.Family , "Happy Fun Times") ), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(Product2.Family , "Kinda Fun" ) ) 
) 
)
```

Now it works when you try to add a product to opp it wont let you unless it's product family is one of those. But no error pops up.....I was thinking about hardcoding this in the handler but I'd rather not.

How does one go about getting that error to appear?

Comment: Hello, can you please provide a screenshot of validation working but not displaying an error message?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for the failure is that the `Product2` relationship is not added to the SObject until after the Save process is completed

Instead, do this as the `PricebookEntry` relationship is known at the beginning of the save process:

```
AND(Opportunity.RecordType.Name = "Happy Fun Times", 
AND(NOT(ISPICKVAL(PricebookEntry.Product2.Family , "Happy Fun Times") ), 
NOT(ISPICKVAL(PricebookEntry.Product2.Family , "Kinda Fun" ) ) 
) 
)
```